# Do I use "する時" or "ている時" when talking about something in general?

Tags: grammar

When something is happening and another thing also happens or is happening in general in English, we can use Verb+ing form after "when" or "whenever" to express the idea, like the two examples below.

**Example 1:**

> When/Whenever I **am watching TV**, my friend annoys me.

**Example 2:**

> When/Whenever I am **doing my homework**, my younger brother is playing video games.

---

**Question:**

If I want to express the same concept in Japanese, do I use "する時" or "ている時"?

> When/Whenever I am watching TV, my friend annoys me.
>
> **Example 3:**
> 私がテレビを**見ている**時、友達が邪魔する。
>
> **Example 4:**
> 私がテレビを**見る**時、友達が邪魔する。

> When/Whenever I am doing my homework, my younger brother is playing video games.
>
> **Example 5:**
> 私が宿題を**している**とき、弟はゲームをやっている。
>
> **Example 6:**
> 私が宿題を**する**とき、弟はゲームをやっている。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to expand a bit on [this question's answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61401/difference-between-%e3%81%9f-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b-plain-form-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8d), which is very similar.

Example 3 is good. It means that when you are watching TV, your friend annoys you.

Example 4 means "right before I watch TV, my friend annoys me" (which is pretty nonsensical...)

Example 5 and 6 have a similar problem. Example 6 means "right before I do my homework, my brother plays games".

In general, if you are in a state when something else happens, use ている to specify that it is indeed a state. Otherwise, if the verb is an action, the meaning changes.

Edit: in response to the comment by a20, I've cited a source for my translations, A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar, page 493:

[image: DBJG, p 493]

Comment: 4 is simply translated as "When I watch TV, my friend bugs me", I do not understand where you get the "right before" from.

Comment: My reference is A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar

Comment: @a20 I've edited the post, how's this

Comment: @Riolku I found this example in the page 491 of the book. It is: 松本さんは朝ご飯を食べる時いつもテレビをみる（Mr. Matsumoto always watches TV when he eats his breakfast.）This means my example 4 can also mean When/Whenever I watch TV, my friend annoys me. I think it is wierd. Can you explain about this topic more?

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand it enough. This sentence given is fine, but I don't know how it differs from 食べている... my guess is that the progressive tense gives more focus to the action of eating

Answer (score 3):

Examples #3 and #5 sound natural for what you mean.

Example #4 is also fine if you are talking about what habitually happens, as opposed to a specific instance in which you are already watching TV and your friend disturbs you. I think you can say “When/Whenever I **watch** TV” in English for this sense, too.

While example #6 could also be understood as referring to a habit, it sounds a bit odd because of the progressive やっている. It sounds as if your brother is already in the middle of playing a game by the time you sit down to do your homework, and that happens every time you do so.